# What is the meaning of tag-mediated?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What are the meaning of "mediate" and "tag-mediated" in the sentence below?

> To test this hypothesis  two  versions  of Echo  were  ran  for  each    experiment, one  in  which  interactions   were  mediated  by  tags  and  conditions (hence   subject  to  coevolution)   and  another  in  which  interactions took place randomly. The tag-mediated simulation fit the data better than the purely random one.

Comment: Does the original say "were ran"?

Comment: Yes, it says "were ran"

Comment: [So, you found a sentence or phrase… (Why you should cite your source)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1084/9161)

Answer (score 1):

**Tag-mediation** describes a process in biological environmental algorithmic simulations whereby instead of purely random interactions between and among the genotypes, interactions are conditioned upon the matching of "tags" (identifying strings of text) which have been prefixed to the data objects that represent the creatures involved in the simulation. These tags are like labels referring to particular states which must obtain or conditions which must be met in order for an interaction to occur between two labelled (or tagged) creatures.